# How to correctly write a raw multiline string in Python?

Tags: python, string, multiline, rawstring

1. I know that you can create a multi-line string a few ways:

**Triple Quotes**

```
'''
This is a 
multi-line
string.
'''
```

**Concatenating**

```
('this is '
'a string')
```

**Escaping**

```
'This is'\
'a string'
```

2. I also know that prefixing the string with `r` will make it a raw string, useful for filepaths.

   ```
   r'C:\Path\To\File'
   ```

However, I have a long filepath that both spans multiple lines and needs to be a raw string. How do I do this?

This works:

```
In [1]: (r'a\b'
   ...: '\c\d')
Out[1]: 'a\\b\\c\\d'
```

But for some reason, this doesn't:

```
In [4]:  (r'on\e'
   ...: '\tw\o')
Out[4]: 'on\\e\tw\\o'
```

Why does the `"t"` only have one backslash?

Comment: `r'''...'''` works just fine to make a raw multiline string.

Comment: @jasonharper No it doesn't, it adds the `\n` for new line:

`In [7]: r'''path\to
   ...: \file'''
Out[7]: 'path\\to\n\\file'`

Comment: The triple quotes are used to create a **multi-line string** (string that contains newlines). Concatenating and escaping are used to create a **multi-line code representation** of a single-line string.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'd need a `r` prefix on each string literal

```
>>> (r'on\e'
     r'\tw\o')
'on\\e\\tw\\o'
```

Otherwise the first portion is interpreted as a raw string literal, but the next line of string is not, so the `'\t`' is interpreted as a tab character.

Comment: That's a pain in the neck for long filepaths. Any other ideas for raw multiline strings?

Comment: @JoshD This is [one of the preferred solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string) for all strings (not just the raw ones) that need to be split over multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might also need to make the second line a raw string as well by prefixing it with the r as you did in `r'on\e'`