# Python - Pyodbc for SQL Anywhere 16?

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a DB via python using Pyodbc as per below:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Anywhere 16};'
                      'Server=***.**.**.***;'
                      'Database=**********;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
                      )

Data = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM * WHERE Date='20180328'", conn)
print(Data)
```

but receive the error:

> line 4, in 
>   conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Anywhere 16};' pyodbc.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Database server
>   not found (-100) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I have a ODBC configuration on Windows with the driver "SQL Anywhere 16" and I can connect through Squirrel SQL using this ODBC connection - any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issue with your connection string to me. Perhaps I am wrong, but it is looking like the error you are facing is it is not finding a server, and bases on the error it looks almost as if you are only getting the `Driver=SQL Anywhere 16` passed to it.

I mention that because in this question:[Connecting to MS SQL Server with Windows Authentication using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515420/connecting-to-ms-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-using-python)

They detail the following for the strings on multiple lines in the answer

```
conn_str = (
r'Driver={SQL Server};'
r'Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;'
r'Database=myDB;'
r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
```

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

Additionally, when searching for multi line strings we see this answer here:[How to correctly write a raw multiline string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003452/how-to-correctly-write-a-raw-multiline-string-in-python)

Which details:

> You'd need a r prefix on each string literal

```
(r'on\e'
     r'\tw\o')
'on\\e\\tw\\o'
```

Otherwise the first portion is interpreted as a raw string literal, but the next line of string is not, so the  '\t' is interpreted as a tab character.

So please try prefixing an r to each line of that literal string to make something more like

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Anywhere 16};'
                      r'Server=***.**.**.***;'
                      r'Database=**********;'
                      r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
                      )

Data = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM * WHERE Date='20180328'", conn)
print(Data)
```

And see if that fixes your problem.

EDIT: I edited to fix formatting.