# How to write patterns for use with re.VERBOSE when they contain meaningful whitespace?

Tags: python, regex, whitespace, flags

Regexes containing meaningful spaces break when re.VERBOSE is added, apparently because re.VERBOSE 'helpfully' magics away the (meaningful) whitespace inside 'Issue Summary', as well as all the crappy non-meaningful whitespace (e.g. padding and newlines inside a (multiline) pattern). (My use of re.VERBOSE with multiline is non-negotiable - this is actually a massive simplification of a huge multiline regex where re.VERBOSE is necessary just to stay sane.)

```
import re
re.match(r'''Issue Summary.*''', 'Issue Summary: fails''', re.U|re.VERBOSE)
# No match!
re.match(r'''Issue Summary.*''', 'Issue Summary: passes''', re.U)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10ba36030>
re.match(r'Issue Summary.*', 'Issue Summary: passes''', re.U)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10b98ff38>
```

Is there a saner alternative to write re.VERBOSE-friendly patterns containing meaningful spaces, short of replacing each instance in my pattern with '\s' or '.', which is not just ugly but counter-intuitive and a pain to automate?

```
re.match(r'Issue\sSummary.*''', 'Issue Summary: fails', re.VERBOSE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10ba36030>
re.match(r'Issue.Summary.*''', 'Issue Summary: fails', re.VERBOSE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10b98ff38>
```

(As an aside, this a useful docbug catch on Python 2 and 3. I'll file it once I get consensus here on what the right solution is)

Comment: Why are you using all the triple quotes?  They aren't helping, and they're obscuring your strings.  `r'''abc'''` is just `r'' + 'abc' + ''`, or `'abc'`.  The `r` isn't even taking effect since it ends after the initial empty string.

Comment: @TomKarzes: as I stated clearly in the question **"This is actually a massive simplification of a huge multiline regex"**. The real regex is actually 14 lines long and growing. It has multiple nested sub-expressions. So like I said, multiline pattern and re.VERBOSE are non-negotiable.

Comment: Ok - it's just that by making them single-line, the meaning of the quotes has changed.

Comment: @TomKarzes: ahh, you're right. Raw multiline string: `r'''this is wrong'''` . The right syntax must use r with double-quotes: `r"""this is right"""`. See [How to correctly write a raw multiline string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003452/how-to-correctly-write-a-raw-multiline-string-in-python). My misconception is due to other people having been spreading the same mistake for years. Related: [Python regex compile (with re.VERBOSE) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761723/python-regex-compile-with-re-verbose-not-working)

Comment: @smci No. The single and double quotes are completely interchangeable. And so are the single and double triple quotes, prefixed or not. See the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783097/when-to-use-triple-single-quotes-instead-of-triple-double-quotes).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `re.VERBOSE` is used, then I think there's no choice other than to change the regular expression string.  However, I would suggest one of the following:

```
r'abc\ def'
```

or:

```
r'abc[ ]def'
```

Both `r'\ '` and `'[ ]'` match a single space character (not any whitespace, only an actual space).  Note that, without the `r` in front, the backslash character would need to be doubled, i.e. `\\`.